# How do I show REST API and Database Connection in UML Class Diagram?

Tags: rest, api, model-view-controller, uml, software-design

I am trying to Create Class Diagram for my Web Application but i dont know how to Represent Database Connection and REST API in Class diagrams.
P.S. I am Creating Class Diagram by following model view controller pattern.

Comment: Please put in some effort your own and do not simply ask for "teh codez".

Comment: I think a deployment diagram in UML is better for representing those details.

Comment: Or component diagram: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geekstore/ppbox/master/ComponentDiagram.png

Answer (score 3):

**A class is a class**

In your class diagrams, you model classes of your system.  And all the classes look alike:

- a database connection would be a class like another, that will keep some properties about the database context and offer methods for connecting to and disconnecting from a given database.
- a REST API class would be a class (or a set of classes) like any other.  If you're the API consumer you would certainly have no properties in these classes (because REST is stateless and properties create a state).  You could for example have a method for every service you could invoke.

Conceptually speaking theses classes in your system are proxies for something which is out of your system, and which would invoke the APIs provided by the database and the webservice.

**But perhaps you want to model something else ?**

If your system offers an API, and you want to show how the API offered to the external world relates to your internal classes, you could be interested in using a [composite structure diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/composite-structure-diagrams.html).

If you want to show the different components if your system, especially how these are wired together using an API, you could be interested in the [component diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html).

If your question is not so much about the structure of the classes and the deeper internals of your system, but more about showing that some part are on remote servers or in containers,  you could even think of [deployment diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams-overview.html).  But these are more about the concrete layout of the operating infrastructure, and to link it to the classes, you'd need the component diagrams first.